# Does $7$ divide $2 x^2 - 4y^2$ for all $x,y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does $7$ divide $2 x^2 - 4y^2$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Have you tried a few examples?

Comment: yes, I tried a few examples, and it seems to work. Proving the general statement is the issue. However, not both $x$ and $y$ can be one.

Comment: Astonishing, for $x = 1,\; y = 0$ leads to $2x^2 - 4 y^2 = 2$. You must have had extraordinary bad luck choosing your examples.

Comment: I tried $(a,b)=(3,1)$ and $(4,1)$, etc. An easy check would have shown it is not true in general. Sorry.

Comment: Don't be sorry. Just bad luck choosing the examples.

Comment: $x=1, y=1$ gives another counterexample as does $x=2, y=1$.

Comment: Well, be a little sorry and learn that 2 examples is way too few examples. Next time try $\;5,6\;$ or more, until you're convinced there's a sound pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = 7a + 1$ and $y = 7b + 1$ for integers $a,b$. Then,

$$\begin{align}2a^2 - 4b^2 &\equiv 2\cdot1^2 - 4\cdot1^2\pmod 7\\
&= 5\pmod7\\
&\equiv 5 \pmod 7\end{align}$$

So it is not generally true, because we can always generate integer pairs (though not all of them) that give a remainder of $5$ when divided by $7$ as shown above. Using the above result, we see that $(x,y) = (1, 1), (8, 1), (1, 8), (8,8)$ are all counter examples.

In fact, you can play around with the constant term in $x$ and $y$ to see how it affects the remainder.

---

However, if $x = 7a + 2$ and $y = 7b + 4$, then we see that

$$\begin{align}2x^2 - 4y^2\equiv2\cdot2^2-4\cdot4^2\pmod7\\
= -56\pmod7\\
\equiv 0 \pmod7\end{align}$$

Hence, the result will hold true if $x = 7a + 2$ and $y = 7b + 4$, for integers $a,b$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing. What's wrong with the answer? I upvote to restore balance.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Perhaps because a simple counter-example suffices. But I up-voted because, while the answer is more complicated than necessary, it at least generalizes to help solve other problems.

Comment: Okay one question though. Is "congruent arithmetic" a real term? Isn't it "modular arithmetic"? I might be wrong.

Comment: @Sabyasachi You are right, I often mix the terminology up.

Comment: You haven't shown that there are any $x$ and $y$ for which $7$ does not divide $2x^2-4y^2$.

Comment: Oh my, I seem to have mistook the question. Modified it now.

Answer (score 0):

...suppose the result holds true, then, 
$2x^2-4y^2=0 \pmod7$ 
since $2$ does not divide $7$, we have $x^2-2y^2=0 \pmod7$, but $2$ is congruent to $9$ modulo $7$, so, $x^2-9y^2=0 \pmod7$ or 
$x=3y \pmod7$, so the result holds true $iff$ $x=3y+7k$, for some integer $k$

Comment: $x = -3y + 7k$ works too. Also, I don't think you can take square roots in modular arithmetic, at least not just like that.

Comment: ...one can freely take square root in modular arithmetic, but one of the two results may not be true, if $x^2=a^2 \pmodN$, then $x^2-a^2=0 \pmodN$, or $(x-a)(x+a)=0 \pmodN$, so either $x-a=0 \pmodN$ or $x+a=0 \pmodN$, if neither is satisfied then the congruent relation is not true afterall

Comment: The relation “$x^2-9y^2\equiv0\pmod{7}$” is equivalent to “$x\equiv3y\pmod{7}$ or $x\equiv-3y\pmod{7}$”. Your “if and only if” conclusion is incorrect.